How to POST complex json object to an ASP.NET Core Web API with model binding
Is there any current solution natively built into ASP.NET Core 8 Web API that allows a complex JSON object to be sent as a [FromForm] or [FromBody] parameter including files/array of files? I am trying to POST the following data from an axios request. My controller looks as follows:
    [HttpPost("")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddDocumentReview([FromForm] UploadedDocumentReviewDTO documentReview)
    {
        return Ok(documentReview);
    }

My model is as follows:
public class UploadedDocumentReviewDTO
{
    [ModelBinder(Name = "review_details")]
    public required UploadedReviewDetailsDTO ReviewDetails {get; set;}
    
    [ModelBinder(Name = "document")]
    public required IFormFile Document {get; set;}
}

My frontend code trying to use FromForm via FormData is as follows:
  const submit = () => {
let form = new FormData();

const reviewDetails : ReviewDetails = {
    rating_period_begin_date: ratingPeriodBeginModel.value!,
    rating_period_end_date: ratingPeriodEndModel.value!,
    document_title: documentTitleModel.value!
}

form.append('review_details' , JSON.stringify(reviewDetails))
form.append('document' , documentModel.value)

api.post('/DocumentReview', form, config).then(response => {

})

}
As you can see my primary model is complex as it has UploadedReviewDetailsDTO object inside of it. This nested object does not not seem to deserialize to the model despite being sent as a parameter and I always get a error that it is missing since its a required object (which it should be as well as its internal components). I tested to see if I changed that UploadedReviewDetailsDTO object to a string instead then it binds great but I was hoping it would deserialize all elements when original binding to the model so that my validation occurs before going into the body of my controller method. I have found one post on stackoverflow using a custom model binder which was posted in 2017 but I was hoping this functionality has since been added via a more native solution built into .NET Core

Not sure why you pass json object for the nested model, actually just append to formdata can also work fine.
Model
public class UploadedDocumentReviewDTO
{
    [ModelBinder(Name = "review_details")]
    public required UploadedReviewDetailsDTO ReviewDetails { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(Name = "document")]
    public required IFormFile Document { get; set; }
}
public class UploadedReviewDetailsDTO
{
    public DateTime RatingPeriodBeginDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime RatingPeriodEndDate { get; set; }

    public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }
}

View
@model UploadedDocumentReviewDTO
<input asp-for="ReviewDetails.RatingPeriodBeginDate" placeholder="Rating Period Begin Date" />
<br>
<input asp-for="ReviewDetails.RatingPeriodEndDate" placeholder="Rating Period End Date" />
<br>
<input asp-for="ReviewDetails.DocumentTitle" placeholder="Document Title" />
<br>
<input asp-for="Document" />
<br>
<button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

@section Scripts
{
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const submit = () => {
            let form = new FormData();
            const ratingPeriodBeginDate = $('#ReviewDetails_RatingPeriodBeginDate').val();
            const ratingPeriodEndDate = $('#ReviewDetails_RatingPeriodEndDate').val();
            const documentTitle = $('#ReviewDetails_DocumentTitle').val();
            const fileInput = $('#Document')[0].files[0]; // Get the file

            // Append the values to the FormData object                
            form.append('review_details.RatingPeriodBeginDate', ratingPeriodBeginDate);
            form.append('review_details.RatingPeriodEndDate', ratingPeriodEndDate);
            form.append('review_details.DocumentTitle', documentTitle);
            form.append('document', fileInput);
              
            // Make the POST request
            axios.post('/DocumentReview', form)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log('Response:', response.data);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error:', error);
                });
        };
    </script>
}

Explanation for code:

asp-for will generate the name name="ReviewDetails.RatingPeriodBeginDate" and id id="ReviewDetails_RatingPeriodBeginDate".

Model binding binds the property by name, so you need pass the form data with key like below by default:
 form.append('ReviewDetails.RatingPeriodBeginDate', ratingPeriodBeginDate);
 form.append('ReviewDetails.RatingPeriodEndDate', ratingPeriodEndDate);
 form.append('ReviewDetails.DocumentTitle', documentTitle);


Because you modify the model binding name by attribute [ModelBinder(Name = "review_details")], so your js should be:
 form.append('review_details.RatingPeriodBeginDate', ratingPeriodBeginDate);
 form.append('review_details.RatingPeriodEndDate', ratingPeriodEndDate);
 form.append('review_details.DocumentTitle', documentTitle);
 form.append('document', fileInput);



BTW, i saw your js pass the json with name like:rating_period_begin_date, it seems you also add the ModelBinder attribute in the UploadedReviewDetailsDTO model? If so, you need pass the form data like:
form.append('review_details.rating_period_begin_date', ratingPeriodBeginDate);
form.append('review_details.rating_period_end_date', ratingPeriodEndDate);
form.append('review_details.document_title', documentTitle);
form.append('document', fileInput);


If you must pass json object for ReviewDetails, custom model binding like below:
Model
public class UploadedDocumentReviewDTO
{
    [ModelBinder(Name = "review_details")]
    public required UploadedReviewDetailsDTO ReviewDetails { get; set; }

    [ModelBinder(Name = "document")]
    public required IFormFile Document { get; set; }
}
public class UploadedReviewDetailsDTO
{
    public DateTime RatingPeriodBeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime RatingPeriodEndDate { get; set; }
    public string DocumentTitle { get; set; }
}

View
**Note:**Because the json string will be deserialized in my custom model binding, so the key name should be RatingPeriodBeginDate instead of rating_period_begin_date. If you must change the name, you need use [JsonPropertyName("rating_period_begin_date")].
const submit = () => {
    let form = new FormData();
    const ratingPeriodBeginDate = $('#ReviewDetails_RatingPeriodBeginDate').val();
    const ratingPeriodEndDate = $('#ReviewDetails_RatingPeriodEndDate').val();
    const documentTitle = $('#ReviewDetails_DocumentTitle').val();
    const fileInput = $('#Document')[0].files[0]; // Get the file
    const reviewDetails = {
        RatingPeriodBeginDate: ratingPeriodBeginDate,
        RatingPeriodEndDate: ratingPeriodEndDate,
        DocumentTitle: documentTitle
    };
    form.append('review_details', JSON.stringify(reviewDetails));
    form.append('document', fileInput);

    // Make the POST request
    axios.post('/DocumentReview', form)
        .then(response => {
            console.log('Response:', response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
};

Custom Model Binding
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
        }

        // Get the FormData from the request
        var form = bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Form;

        // Deserialize the nested JSON object
        var reviewDetailsJson = form["review_details"];
        var reviewDetails = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UploadedReviewDetailsDTO>(reviewDetailsJson);

        // Create the UploadedDocumentReviewDTO instance
        var documentReview = new UploadedDocumentReviewDTO
        {
            ReviewDetails = reviewDetails,
            Document = form.Files.GetFile("document")
        };

        // Set the result to the binding context
        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(documentReview);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Controller
public async Task<IActionResult> DocumentReview([ModelBinder(BinderType = typeof(CustomModelBinder))][FromForm] UploadedDocumentReviewDTO model)


Okay so this did require a custom model binder. Okay hear me out. If I did separate out my object to get the files out and sent all the json data by itself in the nested object to bind to a string parameter. Id have a completely serialized json as a variable which my first line of code could be to deserialize to the object. Once your in the controller action can you use model state to return errors similar to the data annotation validations that happen when the model binding is at the action parameter level?

If you must separate out the file and send other properties as json data, yes you need a custom model binder. For your second question, do you mean you want to judge the ModelState in the action and return validation error? Yes, it can, and it is same as the data annotation validations which happens at action level.

So when I add the deserialize method and try to bind to the model do I just put in a try catch and the exception will be the data annotation errors basically similar to how the controller action parameters work? Thats what I was curious about. I think that would get around needing the custom model binder but I just wasnt sure how to handle the modelstate. Either way I am going to give you answer a try this upcoming week at work.

No. You can manually add the error to ModelState in custom Model Binder, but you can not get the model validaiton error in custom Model Binder, cause Model Binding occurs before Model Validation. You can check the ModelState in controller action.

Does the custom model binder still check for data annotations/validations? Since you deserialize I wasnt sure since deserializing doesnt check for data annotations for validation and binding to the model.

Hi @Qiuzman, I think you may not understand what i said before. Model Binding occurs before Model Validation. You custom model binder to instead the default model binding system. It will not influence the model validation, the model validation will still work as before. You could check ModelState.IsValid in controller action. For you use ajax, it will not display the error message by default,  because ajax cannot refresh the page with response. If you want to display it, you need return the response with error message and do js operation to append the data to frontend in ajax.success function.

I am not using MVC but a SPA and web api. However, that makes sense if the model binder runs before the validation then it should allow the data annotations to take effect.

Correct, no matter Mvc or SPA with web api, the model binding always runs before model validation.

Just as I am learning more on the model binding and validation subject do you prefer fluentvalidation or rely on data annotations?

if you need more advanced validation features, better separation of concerns, and flexibility, FluentValidation is a better choice.
